# SerializeArray on local storage works in local but not on server (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form and I'm storing the user inputs temporarily by getting the SerializeArray and storing it in local storage using localStorage. I'm getting this set item in the next page and displaying the user inputs as a preview form before form submission. The above code works fine in local but when it's deployed to server the inputs are not being stored. When i logged the SerializeArray, it showed 'object' instead of user input values.

Is there something that needs to be done for it to work on server.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: _"The above code works fine in local"_ - what above code, you have not shown any.

Comment: Lmao. I meant the above mentioned implementation.

Comment: We can't possibly help debug code we don't know. [ask], [mre]